# Chrome remote desktop "failed to start remote access service"

Tags: google-chrome, remote-desktop

Trying to run Chrome remote desktop on Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS.

Installed:

- `chrome-remote-desktop_current_amd64.deb`
- `xvfb`
- `python-psutil`

When I try to connect in the app through "enable remote connection" it searches for a while then says "failed to start remote access service".

Answer (score 3):

I had similar problem on xubuntu 14.04.
The last step that solved the problem was to add the user to the group as follows:

```
sudo groupadd chrome-remote-desktop
usermod -a -G chrome-remote-desktop <username>
```

You can check if the user is in the group by:

```
groups <username>
```

before the last step I also followed the linux section in:

https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/1649523?hl=en

Comment: sudo groupadd chrome-remote-desktop usermod -a -G chrome-remote-desktop

Comment: You can [edit] and delete your posts.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem with not being able to activate remote services but I finally got it working without any editing.

- Install remote desktop app in chrome, if your remote connection fails, restart computer then open the app again and try connecting the service again.
- After the service is running, restart again then check your remote device (Phone, Tablet or another PC) and it should be running.

Comment: Maybe a link would be nice.