# Chrome Remote Desktop host setup instructions not showing for Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: google-chrome, remote-desktop, chrome-extension

I'm currently trying to set up chrome remote desktop on a new computer with Ubuntu 18.04. But whenever I try to follow the instructions on https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/1649523#linux-crd, it skips the setup stage and goes straight to "Set up another device for remote access".

To clarify, the steps are:

1. Install chrome extension
2. Install Debian file https://dl.google.com/linux/direct/chrome-remote-desktop_current_amd64.deb
3. Checked that it was successful using `systemctl status chrome-remote-desktop`
4. The blue setup button on https://remotedesktop.google.com/access/ gets stuck forever
5. If I try to open it up in a new tab or refresh, the only option I have is to "Set up another device for remote access" or remote into a device I've setup already.

I've gotten this to work on a virtual machine earlier this year and it works fine on my windows computer. But it seems to only fail on my Ubuntu 18.04 computer. I've also tried reinstalling google-chrome, chrome-remote-desktop chrome extension and chrome-remote-desktop Debian file installation.

Does anyone have suggestions on what might be going on?

Comment: Same symptoms and I found it is because https://askubuntu.com/a/1261797

Comment: same boat on Ubuntu 20.04. I used to make it work before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just checked again and looks like they've fixed it so it works again! If anyone else has this issue, an update should do!

Answer (score 33):

If anyone else has this issue, try this:

```
mkdir ~/.config/chrome-remote-desktop
```

Comment: This helped me. Thank you

Comment: Works like a charm, thanks a lot!

Comment: Worked for me in that session to add this computer to my Google Remote Devices, and it remains functional that way. BUT, a few days later, now I want to share this computer's "access code" so that someone else can take control, and that box at the bottom went back to prompting me to set up remote access.  Same in the "Remote Support" tab: "To let someone else access and control this computer, click the download button." As if I no longer have remote desktop set up. Running the `mkdir` command again returns error `cannot create directory ..... File already exists`.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer.

Comment: Did the trick! Thank you!

Comment: Thank you. It worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

Happened to me with Ubuntu 20+:

I installed Google Chrome and, then, tried to install Chrome Remote Desktop.

Google Chrome tries to open chrome-remote-desktop_current_amd64.deb with Snap Store and then fails.

Solution: install gdebi, make it the default application to open .deb files and try again to install Chrome Remote Desktop.

Comment: Thank you for your contribution - for future documentation purposes, please **edit** your answer and add your full Ubuntu version, not "Ubuntu 20+".

Comment: had this already done -- not working

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem on Ubuntu 21.04, so:

1. Try installing the `.deb` package with `dpkg` and look at the errors.
   Mine for example listed this:

```
$ sudo dpkg -i "./path/to/file.deb"
[sudo] password for user: 

...

dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of chrome-remote-desktop:
chrome-remote-desktop depends on xvfb; however:
  Package xvfb is not installed.
chrome-remote-desktop depends on xbase-clients; however:
  Package xbase-clients is not installed.
chrome-remote-desktop depends on python3-psutil; however:
  Package python3-psutil is not installed.
```

If the output is similar to this, try installing them. Like:

```
$ sudo apt install xvfb xbase-clients python3-psutil
```

Hope this helped.