# Authentication Required Popup

Tags: google-chrome, authentication, remote

Edit: The popup problem is caused by Chrome Remote Desktop. When I uninstalled it, the problem is resolved. However, I want to have this app. How can I manage to have it without seeing disturbing popups?

Edit2: I have installed the CRD following the official website remotedesktop.google.com. It just installs the addon for Firefox, and the CRD package itself. However, I faced another problem, and followed the solution proposed at https://askubuntu.com/a/1306552/1183850. I did not connect to my computer from another device using CRD. Even if I did not connect, I have faced these popups. That is why I am asking for help. I do not want to see these popups when I do not use CRD. If I use it, I will be happy to see these popups.

Today, I have installed Chrome Remote Desktop to my Ubuntu 20.04 LTS machine. However, when I restart my machine, I was asked my password for couple of Authentication Required popups. I was also unable to change my screen brightness (this issue is resolved when I remove my computer from Chrome Remote Desktop). However, the popup thing remains the same. Also, an error message appears everytime I start my computer. How can I solve it?

Also, when I try to shutdown the computer from GUI, there is an "Other users are logged in" warning in the popup. I have never seen it before.
[image: PowerOff]

[image: Color Profile]

[image: System Repo]

[image: Error]

Comment: This is because Chrome Remote Desktop

Comment: Yeah, I uninstalled it, and it seems like the problem is resolved. However, I want the Chrome Remote Desktop. How can I manage to have it without seeing disturbing popups?

Comment: @user535733 I have edited my post. Can you check Edit2?

Comment: I think the question is much clearer for folks to understand now.

Answer (score 2):

A more targeted polkit change that works for me on Ubuntu 20.04 is:

```
[Allow Network Manager for Myself]
Identity=unix-user:USERNAME
Action=org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.*
ResultAny=yes
ResultInactive=yes
ResultActive=yes

[Allow Login, Shutdown, Restart, Etc for Myself]
Identity=unix-user:USERNAME
Action=org.freedesktop.login1.*
ResultAny=yes
ResultInactive=yes
ResultActive=yes

[Allow Colord all Users]
Identity=unix-user:*
Action=org.freedesktop.color-manager.create-device;org.freedesktop.color-manager.create-profile;org.freedesktop.color-manager.delete-device;org.freedesktop.color-manager.delete-profile;org.freedesktop.color-manager.modify-device;org.freedesktop.color-manager.modify-profile
ResultAny=no
ResultInactive=no
ResultActive=yes

[Allow Package Management all Users]
Identity=unix-user:*
Action=org.freedesktop.packagekit.system-sources-refresh
ResultAny=yes
ResultInactive=yes
ResultActive=yes
```

Which I names as /etc/polkit-1/localauthority/50-local.d/45-remote-desktop-sanity.pkla

Of course replace USERNAME with your username, and then restart.

For more information see the following references:

https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/org.freedesktop.login1.html

[https://people.freedesktop.org/~lkundrak/nm-docs/gdbus-org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.html](https://people.freedesktop.org/%7Elkundrak/nm-docs/gdbus-org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.html)

https://www.freedesktop.org/software/colord/gtk-doc/ColorManager.html

https://www.freedesktop.org/software/PackageKit/gtk-doc/PackageKit.html

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same problem after installing the Google Chrome Remote Desktop in my Ubuntu 20.04 and using Firefox as per this guide:
[https://kifarunix.com/install-and-setup-chrome-remote-desktop-on-ubuntu-20-04/\](https://kifarunix.com/install-and-setup-chrome-remote-desktop-on-ubuntu-20-04/%5C)

To solve the issue, at least for now, I have done:

1. Disabled the autologin feature as suggested here: [Ubuntu 21.04 asking for password too often](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1335832/ubuntu-21-04-asking-for-password-too-often). However, I do not think is strictly necessary.

   ```
   sudo nano /etc/gdm3/custom.conf
   ```

   and commented this:

   ```
   #AutomaticLoginEnable=true
   ```
2. I have followed the solution in this article, [xRDP – How to Fix the Infamous system crash popups in Ubuntu 18.04 (and previous versions)](http://c-nergy.be/blog/?p=12043), by doing:

   ```
   sudo nano /etc/polkit-1/localauthority/50-local.d/45-allow-colord.pkla
   ```

   and copied in the text body the following:

   ```
   [Allow Colord all Users]
   Identity=unix-user:*
   Action=org.freedesktop.color-manager.create-device;org.freedesktop.color-manager.create-profile;org.freedesktop.color-manager.delete-device;org.freedesktop.color-manager.delete-profile;org.freedesktop.color-manager.modify-device;org.freedesktop.color-manager.modify-profile
   ResultAny=no
   ResultInactive=no
   ResultActive=yes
   ```

I then rebooted and tested Chrome Remote Desktop and it seems that everything is working, though more testing may be necessary to check if other features were impaired by these tweaks.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I fixed “Authentication is required to create a color profile/managed device”:

The safest fix to get rid of these popups is to create a new configuration file in `/etc/polkit-1/localauthority.conf.d/02-allow-colord.conf`.

```
sudo nano /etc/polkit-1/localauthority.conf.d/02-allow-colord.conf
```

Paste in the following:

```
/etc/polkit-1/localauthority.conf.d/02-allow-colord.conf
polkit.addRule(function(action, subject) {
 if ((action.id == "org.freedesktop.color-manager.create-device" ||
 action.id == "org.freedesktop.color-manager.create-profile" ||
 action.id == "org.freedesktop.color-manager.delete-device" ||
 action.id == "org.freedesktop.color-manager.delete-profile" ||
 action.id == "org.freedesktop.color-manager.modify-device" ||
 action.id == "org.freedesktop.color-manager.modify-profile") &&
 subject.isInGroup("{users}")) {
 return polkit.Result.YES;
 }
});
```

Save the file, exit, and then reboot.

The solution is taken from [this article](https://devanswers.co/how-to-fix-authentication-is-required-to-create-a-color-profile-managed-device-on-ubuntu-20-04-20-10/).

Comment: Please don't use this! I would not recommend this solution because it will break the system sudo command giving errors when you install apps from Snap (as a common example). You can read the comments of the linked article - but I have tried it and got to the same conclusion.  
**The correct solution is the one posted by Ace.C - no errors, sudo works fine.**

Answer (score 0):

[polkit docs](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/polkit/docs/0.105/pklocalauthority.8.html)

Try creating this file `/etc/polkit-1/localauthority/50-local.d/45-allow-whatever.pkla`

```
[Allow me to do whatever I want as long as Im logged in as me]
Identity=unix-user:yourusernamehere
Action=*
ResultAny=yes
ResultInactive=yes
ResultActive=yes
```

It should let you do whatever you want as long as you are logged in as `yourusernamehere`.

Realistically, `yourusernamehere` is probably not your username so be sure to change that. :)

I think you'll need to reboot or re-login for changes to take effect.