# Ubuntu 21.04 asking for password too often

Tags: login, sudo, password, 21.04

On boot it looks like Ubuntu logs me in on its own without asking for password so I can see the desktop and then it asks for password 4 times to:

- create color profile
- refresh system repositories
- create a color managed device
- refresh system repositories

It also asks for password extensively to run innocent commands such as reboot or to open system monitor. This is a fresh install. I'm using Ubuntu 21 because Ubuntu 20.04 LTS didn't work with integrated graphics of core i9-10900k

Why does it do that?

I'd like to change it so it would ask for password less often just like Ubuntu 20.04 would.

Comment: That happens because you explicitly selected that behavior during installation. You can change for what it should be - login with password - in system settings > Users.

Comment: @ChanganAuto  I think the question isn't about this. OS doesn't ask password usually when you try to reboot.

Comment: @deeptionary Yes, it does, if you're issuing a command such as `**sudo** reboot now`.

Comment: If you have asked Ubuntu to auto logon, it will ask for you password to do anything that impinges on the security of your computer.  If you use your password for logon, then the only time afterwards that your password will be required, is if you do something that needs root (sudo) access.

Comment: @ChanganAuto now I got it :) I have never used Ubuntu with auto log-on. Sorry.

Comment: @deeptionary :) As you should, me neither. But actually when rebooting with a command it asks for the password either way, "sudo", you know, and just `reboot` doesn't work. So, this specific situation is unrelated to the main problem/complaint here.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you are right I just had to turn off the auto log on. I had auto log on on just because Wayland which is on by default didn't allow for remote access. I turned Wayland and auto log on off and all works as normal.