# chrome remote desktop not working in ubunto 20.04

Tags: google-chrome, remote-desktop

I want to remotely access my ubuntu 20.04 from macbook pro (specifically with setup via ssh) using chrome remote desktop. It used to work fine before but some issue happend and I am no longer able to connect. I  have installed chrome remote desktop  and have logged in using the same account on both the systems. I can only connect through remote support option. But both `remote access` and `set up via ssh` is not working.

First I tried using "`remote access`" on ubuntu, it led me to install the chrome remote extenion. By continuing, you agree to the Google Terms of Service and Privacy Policy. I accpeted it: sme times it said: `Could not launch the installer. Please try again later`. or `sorry there was problem with intstallation`. Sometime the blue circle keeps revolving around the download icon.

Then I tried installing chrome desktop using `set up via ssh`. I used `sudo dpkg -i`

```
sudo dpkg -i chrome-remote-desktop_current_amd64.deb
Selecting previously unselected package chrome-remote-desktop.
(Reading database ... 291881 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack chrome-remote-desktop_current_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking chrome-remote-desktop (116.0.5845.9) ...
Setting up chrome-remote-desktop (116.0.5845.9) ...
Restarting Chrome Remote Desktop hosts (sessions will be unaffected)...
Processing triggers for systemd (245.4-4ubuntu3.22) ...
Processing triggers for gnome-menus (3.36.0-1ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for desktop-file-utils (0.24-1ubuntu3) ...
Processing triggers for mime-support (3.64ubuntu1) ...
```

I also tried using `sudo apt install`(which also didnot work).  Then I checked the status of installation:

```
systemctl status chrome-remote-desktop
● chrome-remote-desktop.service
     Loaded: masked (Reason: Unit chrome-remote-desktop.service is masked.)
     Active: inactive (dead)
```

Moreover I used:

```
 service "chrome-remote-desktop@$USER" status
● chrome-remote-desktop@sidra.service - Chrome Remote Desktop instance for sidra
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/chrome-remote-desktop@.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Fri 2023-07-21 16:45:14 IST; 37min ago
   Main PID: 995 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Jul 21 16:45:12 sidra-server systemd[1]: Started Chrome Remote Desktop instance for sidra.
Jul 21 16:45:13 sidra-server systemd[995]: pam_unix(chrome-remote-desktop:session): session opened for user sidra by (uid=0)
Jul 21 16:45:14 sidra-server systemd[1]: chrome-remote-desktop@sidra.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Jul 21 16:45:14 sidra-server systemd[1]: chrome-remote-desktop@sidra.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

As stated above there is issue with instllatalation, so obviously when when I copied the token from macbook and paste it in ubuntu terminal it didnot work

> DISPLAY= /opt/google/chrome-remote-desktop/start-host
> --code="4/0AZEOvhU6VSlam7fDLDoRjD7n86PbEgl_AyjSFXWY22-01RrzizmmEIvZKaLBfaa-E7ys5g"
> --redirect-url="https://remotedesktop.google.com/_/oauthredirect" --name=$(hostname)

it throws error:

```
 (hostname)
[0721/171137.850569:ERROR:usage_stats_consent_linux.cc(37)] No host config file found. Enter a PIN of at least six digits:
```

as there is already error so when i enter the password, `[0721/171240.560099:ERROR:daemon_controller_delegate_linux.cc(207)]` Failed to start host.
Couldn't start host.
Can anyone guide me how can I resolve. I tied alot of online available solutions but nothing worked.

Comment: Possible duplicate of: https://askubuntu.com/questions/962368/cant-configure-chrome-remote-desktop

Comment: try making ".chrome-remote-desktop-ses" file in yo home dir. with "exec /usr/bin/gnome-session" in file.

Comment: @petep I am not aware how to do that? can you please guide me about it?

Comment: @Luuk I had tried that link already, it didnot work.

Comment: just type "echo exec /usr/bin/gnome-session >~/.chrome-remote-desktop-session"